# jquery .offset().top - a set amount of pixels (issues with FF and IE)

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, firefox, offset

So I am using Anchor Slider by Cedric Dugas. What happens is someone clicks a link and it scrolls the page down to the element with the same ID as the link's href... all standard stuff.

But what I want to happen is have it come to a stop at about 80 pixels above that id... so here's what I have.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.anchorLink").anchorAnimate()
});

jQuery.fn.anchorAnimate = function(settings) {

    settings = jQuery.extend({
        speed : 500
    }, settings);   

    return this.each(function(){
        var caller = this
        $(caller).click(function (event) {  
            event.preventDefault()
            var locationHref = window.location.href
            var elementClick = $(caller).attr("href")

            var destination = $(elementClick).offset().top - 80;
            $("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").animate({ scrollTop: destination}, settings.speed, function() {
                window.location.hash = elementClick
            });
            return false;
        })
    })
};
```

This is the line of code that moves it up 80 pixels

```
var destination = $(elementClick).offset().top - 80;
```

The problem is that it works fine in webkit browsers, but in FF and IE, it will stop 80 pixels above then suddenly shift down to where it normally stop.

Anyone have any ideas as to why this happens?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an example online? Perhaps one using http://jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 1):

This is the natural behavior of the browser. When you visit a url that contains a fragment, the browser attempts to navigate to the element corresponding to the fragment. So https://stackoverflow.com/#h-recent-tags would result in the browser scrolling down (or over) to the element having the ID of `h-recent-tags`.

Your code is instructing the browser to navigate to this element when it issues the following command:

```
window.location.hash = elementClick;
```

This happens *after* your animation is complete, which is why you see the browser immediately jump up from where it was.

In order to get the effect you're looking for, a different approach needs to be taken. In newer browsers you'll be better off using `pushState`, rather than tampering with the fragment directly:

```
history.pushState(null, null, elementClick);
```

This will update the hash, without affecting the page. But note, this only works in *modern* browsers. With regards to older versions of IE, you'll need to take a different approach. One such approach is to fallback to using the `location.hash` approach, but set the hash before you scroll:

```
$(caller).on("click", function (event) {
    // Prevent default behavior of anchor
    event.preventDefault();

    // Get href value from anchor clicked
    var elementClick = $(caller).attr("href");

    // If the browser supports the History api, use it to update hash
    // Otherwise update hash before we animate the scrolling
    if (history && history.pushState) {
        history.pushState(null, null, elementClick);
    } else {
        window.location.hash = elementClick;
    }

    // Determine where 80px above target is
    var destination = $(elementClick).offset().top - 80;

    // Scroll to that new location
    $("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").animate({
        scrollTop: destination
    }, settings.speed);
});
```

In older browsers this results in immediately going to the target place, and then slowly scrolling up to give some padding.

Answer (score 0):

There are many semicolons missing. It's possible that some browsers are misreading the code because of that. Paste the script into [jshint](http://jshint.com/) to see all the missing semicolons.

**EDIT**

Although the above is a problem, I'm changing my answer. I'll bet it's actually from the line that sets window.location.hash. Doing so probably causes some browsers to jump to that point in the document, which would happen right after the animation finishes.

This is probably the only way to "fix" it without removing that line:

```
var destination = $(elementClick).offset().top;
$("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").animate({ scrollTop: destination}, settings.speed, function() {
    window.location.hash = elementClick;
    $("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").animate({ scrollTop: destination - 80 }, settings.speed);
});
```

In other words, scroll down all the way to the anchor, then set the hash, then scroll back up a bit. You could use easing to make it look more smooth.